# using qt creator only as editor: are qt libraries necessary

Tags: c++, qt, editor

I want to use qt creator, only as an editor, which does code completion and finds declarations etc. I dont want to use it to build etc. Is there a way, I can circumvent the need of qt-libraries? I am using a server, where my file space is limited. Also, without qt libraries, it does not allow making even a project. When I tried to install qt-libraries, it configures fine, but on make gives error.

So, can you suggest an alternative? Thanks

Comment: are you programming with qt without libraries, but headers only? for code completions you need at least headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need the Qt libs because the editor was coded in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Actually - at least under Windows -, you can. You just have to deselect all Qt library versions and only select the editor. If you want to have a debugger available on Windows, also select the checkbox for CDB support.

I have forgotten how this works with the Linux installer, but I imagine the same applies there as well, except of course for the CDB debugger, which is not available on Linux. Instead you should be able to chose from GDB and some other alternatives, though it might not be during the installation.

Once you installed it and are about to set up a new "Plain C++" project, you can't select a Qt version when creating a new kit, obviously.
If you blindly selected an already existing kit, Qt Creator might have tried to use a Qt installation for your vanilla C++ project. Instead of doing so, you should click the "Manage..." button on one of your preexisting kits and add a new, custom kit. Here you can set the "Qt version" option to "None". The rest should be set according to your needs.